# How to check what data pickled between processes

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, python-multiprocessing, mmap

I have the following:

```
from struct import pack_into
from mmap import mmap
from multiprocessing import Pool


mem_label = "packed_ints"
total = 5 * 10**7


def create_mmap(size = total):
    ''' Seems only the Windows version of mmap accepts labels '''

    is_this_pickled = mmap(-1, total * 4, mem_label)


def pack_into_mmap(idx_nums_tup):

    idx, ints_to_pack = idx_nums_tup
    pack_into(str(len(ints_to_pack)) + 'i', mmap(-1, total * 4, mem_label) , idx*4*total//2 , *ints_to_pack)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    create_mmap()
    ints_to_pack = range(total)

    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(pack_into_mmap, enumerate((ints_to_pack[:total//2], ints_to_pack[total//2:])))
```

I "hid" the initial mmap inside a function, but I would like to know for certain what is being pickled.

Can I monitor / tap into that information in Python?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking how to tell which information is inherited and which information is pickled when using a `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: Your code example seems to need some cleanup to be a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A few of the issues include: Missing `from multiprocessing import Pool` and not defining the `pack_into()` function

Comment: Apologies and thank you for pointing it out, fixed the code

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if there is an easy way to tell what information is pickled and what information is inherited when using `multiprocessing.Pool`. However, in your code example, I am confident that the `is_this_pickled` variable is in fact **not** pickled since it is never passed to the `Pool` object in any fashion. The underlying `mmap` object should be inherited by child processes.